# Gatsby autolink headers not generating anchor links

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to get autolink headers to work for one of my project.

Reference: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-autolink-headers/#gatsby-remark-autolink-headers

Here is my sample [code](https://github.com/raghudinkavijaykumar/gatsby-autolink-header.git) Commit: 5ae7114

The sample mdx is hosted at `http://localhost:8000/sample` on `yarn start`.

gatsby-config.js

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `./src/pages/`,
      },
      __key: `pages`,
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `sample`,
        path: `./src/content/sample/docs/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
      options: {
        name: `sample`,
        path: `./src/content/sample/docs/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-autolink-headers`,
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Removed unnecessary code. sorry was in a hurry.

Comment: Have you tried removing the empty options object `{}`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu yes. doesn't help. I was trying to pass in arguments, but all are optional.

Comment: Try playing around moving the position of the whole `gatsby-transformer-remark` plugin

Comment: @FerranBuireu I have come across plugin ordering issues but that wasn't the case here. thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to consider

> `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` doesn't create remark processed html pages rather plain md/mdx files from graphql nodes `mdx` not `markdownRemark` (I used this to post the sample question) (went though the docs could't find remark version of this or configuration)

> I had to create `gatsby-node.js` for new page creation and graphql node update with paths.

Sample blog template

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import React from "react";

export default (props) => {
  const { html} = props.data.markdownRemark;
  return (
          <section dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
  query PostsBySlug($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
    }
  }
`;
```

[Code](https://github.com/raghudinkavijaykumar/gatsby-autolink-header/tree/e8b22fea3a52a24e3f6dd6d0aef6e2dd4d6686c6)

Comment: moved the content folder, out of src, just keeping md files separate, added md extension to gatsby-plugin-mdx, md was sufficient for me.